# TF-IDF Weighting after NLTK pre-processing

Tags: python, preprocessor, tf-idf

I am doing some textual preprocessing prior to machine learning. I have two features (Panda series) - `abstract` and `title` - and use the following function to preprocess the data (giving a numpy array, where each row contains the features for one training example):

```
def preprocessText(data):
    stemmer = nltk.stem.porter.PorterStemmer()
    preprocessed = []
    for each in data:
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(each.lower().translate(xlate))
        filtered = [word for word in tokens if word not in stopwords]
        preprocessed.append([stemmer.stem(item) for item in filtered])
    print(Counter(sum([list(x) for x in preprocessed], [])))
    return np.array(preprocessed)
```

I now need to use TF-IDF to weight the features - how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you have list of filtered words in `preprocessed` variable. One way to do TF-IDF transformation is to use `scikit-learn`, [`TfidfVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html). However, the class tokenizes the space for you i.e. you can provide list of processed documents each contain string. So you have to edit your code to:

```
preprocessed.append(' '.join([stemmer.stem(item) for item in filtered]))
```

Then you can transform list of documents as follows

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf_model = TfidfVectorizer() # specify parameters here
X_tfidf = tfidf_model.fit_transform(preprocessed)
```

The output will be matrix in sparse compressed sparse row (CSR) format where you can transform to numpy array later on.

`tfidf_model.vocabulary_` will contain dictionary map of stemming words to id.